# Не получается присвоить стили элементам

Tags: php, css

Блин сижу уже 2 дня голову ломаю , знаю что вопрос глупый но все же.
Пытался подключить посредством echo link rel в php документе , пытался прямо в документу написать теги style style , ничего не выходит стили не присваиваются к форме обратной связи. Может быть я что-то не понимаю , подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить данную ситуацию, как подключить стили , мне нужно навести красоту)

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
<label for="name">Имя</label> <input maxlength="30" id="textbox" type="text" 
name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"> <br>
 <br>
<label for="phone">Тел.:</label> <input maxlength="30" type="text" 
name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон"> <br>
 <br>
 <label for="mail">E-mail</label> <input maxlength="30" type="text" 
name="mail" placeholder="Ваш email"> <br>
 <br>
 <label for="message">Сообщение:</label> <textarea rows="7" cols="50" 
name="message" placeholder="Краткое описание услуги,которую вы хотите 
заказать"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Сам документ является index.php

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем как обычно , написал о помощи и нашел сам решение через 2 минуты , я присваивал класс для label а нужно было для input , да простит меня всевышний , всем спасибо )